# Можно ли как то реализовать такой вид для папки внутри образа диска

Tags: windows, iso-образ

У меня есть образ диска, который я хочу кастомизировать. Можно ли реализовать что то похожее на это с внутренней памятью диска, то есть что бы папка или нечто похожее отображалось таким образом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В корне диска создаём текстовый файл autorun.inf со следующим содержимым:

```
[autorun]
icon=icon.ico
label=Текст_Метки
```

Соответственно в корне также должна быть пиктограмма icon.ico . Но работать это будет только при условии, что в системе включен автозапуск с дисков.